# python subprocess, redirecting exit code to a file

Tags: python, subprocess

Using subprocess run()/popen(), we are able redirect stdout and stderr to an external file. Is there any way to also redirect exit code as well?

Comment: How about `r = subprocess.run(...)` and write `r.returncode` to a file in python?

Comment: No, because that's not how the operating system under it works.

Comment: See `man wait(2)`, and don't use the `run` function. That's a convenience function. You can get more control of the subprocess by using the Popen directly.

Comment: If your sub-processes are modifiable in source code, you can intercept most kill signals, and save state quickly and exit honouring the signal. Know that SIGKILL (9) can't be intercepted, and it destroys the process no matter the state it is in.

Comment: @keith I meant popen(). I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @Harsh, Thanks, yes that was my plan B if there is no way to get subprocess do this.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the returncode attribute of the returned object of `subprocess.run`, and write that to a file.

```py
import subprocess

r = subprocess.run(["ls"])
with open("returncode.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(r.returncode))
```

Comment: my calling function may get killed during course of execution of subprocess.run(), is there any way I can specify this within the run() function?

Comment: well, as far as i know if the calling function gets killed, the program you ran with subprocess will stop immediately and not produce an exit code @GauravPathak

Comment: `returncode` is an integer. It needs to be serialized in some way before write.

Comment: @GauravPathak But may you tell me more details about how the calling function gets "killed" ?

Comment: @Programmer, its a daemon, running on client, getting instructions from server, and subsequently invoking subprocess commands for local execution, there may be some scenarios during client server communication where we may have to restart the daemon, when the daemon restarts, I want the new daemon to know the status of subprocess commands that were initiated by the old daemon that got killed.

Comment: @GauravPathak This is not possible, sorry.

Comment: I got this idea that you can store the state of daemon during process and once old daemon killed and new deamon spawned, it will fetch state from store

Comment: return codes are small integers. They differ by operating system and what the implementor choses to return. On posix systems you either get something > 128 or a negative number, which is the singal number of what killed the process. On Windows there are a lot of standard error codes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes). But if your goal is to ensure that daemon commands are executed, you'll need to record the commands you want and the returns you've got. You could potentially use sqlite that holds a queue of tasks and completions.

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, but it's up to the OP to implement that, could you please post the comment on his question ?

Comment: @programmer - OP commented _my calling function may get killed during course of execution_ and my comment was a description of how you can know what killed the process from the return code. I think it would be a bit out of place in the original question which asks how you save the return code, not how you interpret it.